# How do you get ecommerce stuff into an organic listing?

Tags: google-search, microdata, microformats

I did a search for "eve mattress" & noted that they have a worked credit example in the organic listing - searching the page source doesn't show that this is done using microdata like: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products

https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.evemattress.co.uk%2Fmattress.html

How is this credit example worked into an organic listing?

[image]

Comment: These appear to be a part of the featured snippets that Google provides which are not rich snippets. Featured snippets can gather data from anywhere on the page and seems to prefer data structured in tables and other HTML. In this case, what you are seeing is the first of the option tag results on the page. I did not dig into this, however, you will see that it you update the option, the price changes. It is likely that this is where the snippet comes from. This effect is highly dependent upon the search query and may not always show. Cheers!!

Comment: @closenet I'm not sure about the table container being essential as the next example I looked at wasn't in a table

Comment: It is not always tables, it can be ordered or unordered lists, div tables, text based lists not using HTML, etc., are all used. Well before markup, well before the public awareness of the knowledge graph, extraction of data such as names, addresses, authorship, etc., was done using a long series of parsing methods. Soon after, data itself was being parsed and put into a semantic link structure to better focus results to search queries long before the knowledge graph appeared. This has been done for a long time now.

Comment: @closenet thanks for the additional information, makes a lot of sense.  Lumme authorship, forgot that one!

Answer (score 1):

@closetnoc appears to be right that these are not rich snippets but what are called featured snippets.

These snippets appear to be transitory as the "eve mattress" featured snippets have been replaced by site links.  But looking at two worked examples on www.evemattress.co.uk & shop.silentnight.co.uk it looks like Google favours well structured html elements that are named using words like price (for price) rather than a specific container like a table.

So to answer the question, use well structured html & identify ecommerce elements with unambiguous class/id names.

Google Search "eve mattress"

[image: eve mattress search]

Page & HTML

[image: eve mattress html]

Google Search "safe nights silentnight"

[image: safe nights Silentnight search]

Page & HTML

[image: shop silentnight html]

Comment: Silent night uses http://schema.org/Product to display pricing in search results. The other site is probably listed in [Google Shopping](https://www.google.com/intl/en/retail/shopping-campaigns/) which supports  [Products Feed Specifications](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/188494).